# How can I only preload modules whose parents have been activated?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have lazy loading implemented. I'm trying to set up a [custom preloading strategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#custom-preloading-strategy).

Say I have the following url structure:

```
/
/fruit
/fruit/bananas
/fruit/apples
/vegetables
```

If I hit `/`, I want to preload `/fruit`. Following the Angular example, I simply put `data: {preload: true}` in my route config, and then implement a custom preloading strategy which checks that data and loads. This works fine.

However, I don't want to preload `/bananas` or `/apples` until I actually *navigate* to `/fruit`. As it is, as soon as `/fruit` is preloaded, the preloading strategy finds more modules with `{preload: true}` and preloads `/bananas` and `/apples` too.

Is there a clean way to put off preloading modules after their parent modules have been navigated to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up doing a custom but scalable solution using the route's `data` property. I created 3 properties:

- `preload` (boolean) - if true, preload as soon as Angular knows about it (like `/fruit`). This is the basic example Angular gave us in their docs
- `preloadCheckpoint` (enum) - I define each app "checkpoint" in my own enum. So in my question's example, `/fruit` is the checkpoint, and I'd define on it `data: {preloadCheckpoint: myCheckpointEnum.FRUIT}`
- `preloadAfterCheckpoint` (enum) - I define this to put off preloading until a certain checkpoint is reached. If I define this on `/bananas`, the bananas module won't load until the route with the `FRUIT` checkpoint is defined

I subscribe to route changes so I can keep my checkpoints list updated, and then check that list during every preload attempt.

```
export class CustomPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  checkpoints: Set<PreloadCheckpoints> = new Set<PreloadCheckpoints>(); 

  constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute){

    router.events.pipe(
     filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => route),
      map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild; //gets the deepest child
        return route;
      }),
      filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'))
      .subscribe((route) => {
         if(route.snapshot.data['preloadCheckpoint'] !== undefined){ 
           this.checkpoints.add(route.snapshot.data['preloadCheckpoint']);
         }
    });
  }

  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {    
    if (route.data && ( route.data['preload'] || this.checkpoints.has(route.data['preloadAfterCheckpoint']) )){
      return load(); //preload this route
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  }
}

export enum PreloadCheckpoints {
  FRUIT
}
```

Comment: Does this approach use forChild, or are all of the lazy loaded routes in the app routing module?  I can't seem to get this type of functionality to work with lazy loaded routes' _children_ routes, as they do not show up in the preload (nor does the parent lazy loaded route when hitting the lazy loaded root).

Comment: The `forChild` signature doesn't have a `config` parameter, so I guess it's only for `forRoot`. However, I didn't have any issues preloading routes in lazy loaded modules. You will need to make sure that you load/preload the modules that contain those routes though, as Angular couldn't know about them to preload them otherwise. Does that help?

Comment: Actually yes that helps, as the last part of your comment was actually the reason I was asking, since the child sub-routes were not being passed to the pre-loader.  One thing I'm still confused about though, is when hitting a parent lazy loaded route and loading the module containing sub-routes, they still don't get added in the `preload` method and so I don't have a way to pre-load _from_ that point.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Say you have 3 modules, A B and C. A lazy loads B, and B lazy loads C. You're saying that the app preloads B but not C? It's been a few months but I'm pretty sure that worked fine for me. You could test it pretty easily by using `PreloadAllModules` and seeing if your child modules are loaded. If they are, then you're doing something wrong in your custom one. Try making a stackblitz that reproduces it maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I've been in meetings all day. [Just set this up on my train-ride.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y91n6d).  Basically, what I'm asking is that your method uses the router events to grab a current route and if it contains the data for preload checkpoint, then preload sub routes (from what I understand).  In the example here, if I were to visit the *contracts* route, the preload method only outputs the *random* route.  How would I preload all contract sub-routes without having access to this in the preload method?

Comment: You can't preload a `route`. You can only preload `module`s, which may *contain* routes. In your example, the `contracts.routing.module` doesn't reference any new modules (ie. `loadChildren`). As you've written it, you've *already loaded* `contracts.module` and both the `ContractComponent` and `ContractsComponent` that it declares. There's nothing left to load that would concern your preloading strategy. Does that help?

Comment: Hah, you're right.  [I just reworked it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y91n6d) to have a `contract.module` for the contract route and it does show up when I hit the /contracts route.  This should work for me, even with the extra overhead of modules at that level.  I appreciate you helping me understand eager/lazy loading and how it works a bit!